# ModuleNotFoundError in spacy version 3.3.1 tried previous mentioned solution not working

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, lemmatization, spacy-3

```
  import spacy

     from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer

     from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES

     lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)

     lemmatizer('chuckles', 'NOUN')
```

the output should be chuckle.
using version 3.1.1

Comment: What is the output instead?

Comment: module not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they've changed the way the lemmatizer is instantiated but the following should work...

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['ner', 'tagger', 'parser', 'lemmatizer'])
lemmatizer = nlp.get_pipe('lemmatizer')
t = nlp('chuckles')[0]  
t.pos_ = 'NOUN'
lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(t)[0]
print(lemma)
# >> chuckle
```

It's unfortunate that you have to call the lemmatizer with a `Token` but looking at the code, I don't see a way to call it with `(word, pos)`. I think you're stuck with calling the empty pipeline with a single word to get a `Token` then manually setting the `pos_` before calling `lemmatize(t)`.

Note that the POS tagger will not work correctly on a single word. It only works in sentences and will probably always assign NOUN for pos if you only have one word. This is why I've disabled the pipeline and set `t.pos_` manually.

BTW.. if you only need to lemmatize, you might look at [lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) which is simpler for single word and also more accurate.

Comment: your code works fine. but I just started NLP so didn't get some of the code like why disable lemmatizer ,then calling it with a method. I'm following this book trying its examples.

Comment: The disable in the `load` statement stops the annotators from running when you call `nlp(...)`.  Since you're calling `lemmatize()` manually below there's no reason to run it twice.  The above code is very odd because Spacy isn't intended to run on a single token.  It's made to work on a full sentence.  Normally you would leave the annotators enabled and call `nlp(..)` with the sentence.  The returned `doc` would then contain all the annotations.